# JAVA ¿Cómo introducir la ruta de un fichero por teclado?

Tags: java, scanner

ocupo modificar este método para que la ruta del fichero sea introducida por el usuario. Lo que quiero es que el usuario tenga que copiar y pegar, o escribir, usando el Scanner, la ruta del archivo y se guarde de alguna forma y se coloque dentro de FileReader.

```
//Método para Leer el fichero
public static void leerFichero() {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ruta;
        System.out.println("Introduzca la ruta del fichero que desea leer");
        ruta = sc.nextLine();
        ruta = ruta.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        System.out.println(ruta);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ruta));
        String linea = "";
        while (linea != null) {
            linea = br.readLine();
            if (linea != null) {
                System.out.println(linea);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("No se ha encontrado el archivo." + ex);
    }
}
```

Cuando coloco la ruta me imprime: 
"Introduzca la ruta del fichero que desea leer
C:\Users\Raúl\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ficheros\fichero.txt
C:\Users\Ra�l\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ficheros\fichero.txt
No se ha encontrado el archivo.java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ra�l\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ficheros\fichero.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)"

Comment: Imagino que tu problema se encuentra en que al copiarla directo al scanner y pasandola en una variable por el filereader no la reconoce cierto? o no sabes como usar un scanner? Espero que nada de esto suene como una ofensa pero necesito contexto de esto para contestarte y saber cual es el problema exacto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el problema es como yo pienso lo unico que tendrias que hacer seria remplazar las diagonales que ponga el usuario por dos diagonales para que el fileReader lo pueda leer correctamente asi que lo unico que tendrias que hacer seria usar.

> El doble backslash te permite hacer un escape de caractes especial por lo cual para detectar cada slash necesitas uno que vaya detras de el. El `\\` equivale realmente a `\`.

```
public static void leerFichero() {
    try {

Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cadena;

        System.out.println("Dame cadena: ");
        cadena = out.nextLine();
        cadena = cadena.replace("\\", "\\\\");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cadena));        
        String linea = "";
        while (linea != null) {
            linea = br.readLine();
            if(linea!=null){
                System.out.println(linea);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex ) {
        System.out.println("No se ha encontrado el archivo."+ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: no es eso, lo que quiero es basicamente guardar en un string o algo, la ruta que yo le dé por teclado y que se muestre con el filereader

Comment: Entonces solo usa el `System.out.println("Dame cadena: ");` y el `cadena = out.nextLine();` y ya estarias guardando en una variable el valor que tu ingreses por teclado.

Comment: sii, mira la modificación que he hecho. Pero aún así no me funciona, me dice que  está mal la ruta (lo hice con \\)

Comment: @RaúlRamos por eso es que te agregue el otro codigo el de `cadena = cadena.replace("\\", "\\\\");` para que te remplazara todas las diagonales por doble diagonal porque ninguna de las funciones de java de filereader o bufferreader leen las direcciones solamente con una diagonal.

Comment: @RaúlRamos Tu le estas queriendo colocar un string con una ruta simple en donde tengas una sola diagonal y eso jamas lo detectara.

Comment: Lo acabo de modificar nuevamente, coloqué el relace. Pero al poner la ruta, me sigue saliendo que no la encuentra :(

Comment: Imprime la ruta despues de que pasa el `replace` para saber si te esta devolviendo una ruta valida y pon en tu pregunta que es lo que te imprime con una ruta de ejemplo.

Comment: Hecho, me hace correctamente el cambio de "\" a "\\". Pero sigue sin encontrar la ruta(que está bien porqué la estoy copiando directamente del fichero) aunque le añado el nombre del fichero + .txt. Esta es la ruta que estoy introduciendo: "C:\Users\Raúl\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ficheros\fichero.txt"

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, el problema era el caracter inválido en mi nombre de usuario!

Comment: hola @RaúlRamos no había podido responder, pero eso iba a decirte, en windows tienes problema al intentar acceder a un fichero con ese tipo de caracteres, en linux hice las pruebas y no hay problema, pero si vi que al arrastrar un archivo y posicionarlo en el terminal de linux, fallaba, era porque a la ruta le anexa al inicio y final la comilla simple, para que lo tengas en cuenta. En cuanto a \, no hay inconveniente si lo dejas tal cual como lo recibes. puedes omitir el replace